# Canvas in Javascript only works when there is no other html code

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a drawing canvas first on a html page without any code to train, then i added it to my main html page but it wasnt working and there wasnt any errors in the console. I tried to remove all the css, still didnt work then i tried to delete all the html except the canvas and it worked. It also worked when i added it to the first line of code in the body, i tried to change the position whith position absolute and it didnt work again.

```
class signature{
    constructor(){
        this.canvas  = document.querySelector('canvas');
        this.bouton = document.querySelector('button');
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.dessin = false;
        this.start ();
        this.ctx.stroke();
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    //sizing  
    tailleCanvas(){
        this.canvas.width= 200;
        this.canvas.height= 200;
    }

    //start the drawing
    start (){
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>{
            this.dessin = true;
            this.draw();
        });
    };

    //draw
    draw(){
            this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e)=>{
                if (!this.dessin) return;
                this.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
                this.ctx.lineTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
                this.ctx.stroke();
            })       
    };

    //stop drawing
    stop(){
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ()=>{
            this.dessin = false;
            this.ctx.beginPath();
        });
    };

    //clean canvas
    bouttonSup(){
        this.bouton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move your js file after body tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas>

    </canvas>
    <button>Button</button>
</body>
<script>
    class signature {
        constructor() {
            this.canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            console.log(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            this.bouton = document.querySelector('button');
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
            this.dessin = false;
            this.start();
            this.ctx.stroke();
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }

        //sizing
        tailleCanvas() {
            this.canvas.width = 200;
            this.canvas.height = 200;
        }

        //start the drawing
        start() {
            this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
                this.dessin = true;
                this.draw();
            });
        };

        //draw
        draw() {
            this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
                if (!this.dessin) return;
                this.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
                this.ctx.lineCap = 'round';
                this.ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
                this.ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
                this.ctx.stroke();
            })
        };

        //stop drawing
        stop() {
            this.canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                this.dessin = false;
                this.ctx.beginPath();
            });
        };

        //clean canvas
        bouttonSup() {
            this.bouton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            })
        }
    }
    let data = new signature();
</script>

</html>
```

the reason is before loading your page its calling this document.queryselector for canvas but at that time this canvas was not present. or maybe when you instansitate object for your class use settimeout for 2 sec or 1 sec and then try if it works. anyway using setTimeout is not a good solution

Comment: The sizing function is working, just not the drawing, i first thought it was probleme with the z-index, but it wasnt